# Rails AJax get dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

HI I am beginner in rails noe I am working with a music player application in rails 4 using jplayer and to create a play list I am using Ajax function

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url:"../albums.json",
    success: function(data){
                  myPlaylist.add({title:$(this).attr("names")})
                                        },
    error: function(xhr,status,error){
                      alert(error);
                    }
    });
```

what I want is to pass single album like albums/3.json to Ajax URL when I click the particular album to play ...any ideas will be welcome

Comment: You can add an html data-attribute and give value of album_id. Then change the ajax URL to `url: "/albums" + $(this).data('album_id') + ".json"`

Comment: thanks Santhosh for care taking reply now how to pass the album_id to ajax by using controller or click function?

Comment: First add the data attribute to the HTML. Now I assume you are already triggering the function which makes the AJAX call. In that function, read the HTML attribute by accessing the element via `$(this)`, and use it to construct the URL.

Comment: <td><%= link_to image_tag(album.cover_url(:thumb)), album_path(album),:id => "album" %></td>    this is my index file which is to be clicked and to play how i can pass the album_id by using this? like :data => album.id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're a beginner, let me explain for you

---

**Ajax**

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) stands for **Asynchronous Javascript And XML** - it's designed to send requests in parallel to your standard HTTP requests. This basically means you're able to request data from the server *without reloading* the page.

The problem most people have is they think Ajax is this black magic trick; it's really just Javascript sending a request to your server on your behalf.

When you send a request with Ajax, you need to be able to send to the right data to the right URL, and then process the response accordingly.

I only learnt that a long time after I started with software, so I hope it helps.

--

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :albums #-> domain.com/albums/[:id]
```

The first step you need to take is to define your routes correctly. As Rails uses a [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) structure (the routes are constructed *around* various controller-centric resources, you'll be able to use

When you send a request to `albums/x.json`, you're really sending the request to the `show` action of the `albums` resource,  which you'll need to have ready

--

**Controller**

When you set up your routes, you'll need to be able to handle the JSON request through your controller. You'll do this with the [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) block:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
Class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @album = Album.find params[:id]

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @album.to_json} 
        end
    end
end
```

--

**UJS**

Finally, you'll be best using [Rails' UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) for this - UJS is designed to send `ajax` requests (amongst other things) without you having to write any JS code.

```
#app/views/controller/index.html.erb
<%= link_to "Play", @album, remote: true, format: :json %>
```

You'll then be able to capture the response using standard JS with some of the [UJS ajax event hooks](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:complete", "#link", function(data){
   //stuff here
});
```

Comment: hey Rich Thanks again as usual your answers explain very nicely.. I am learning AJAX.. is there any easiest and nicely describing place?? do u have any blog??

Comment: No blog right now - what do you need to know about Ajax? I can update the answer if you like

Comment: I am completely fresher for Ajax.. so wanted to learn basics..u have extremely knowledge of ROR so I would like to suggest start writing Blog with latest features..

Comment: hey thanks Rich , though I have no reputation in stack overflow I cant able to vote for your answer will try this

Comment: Thanks `@Gagan` - I'm going to write that down to do. Have been meaning to do for some time, but have been busy with other things. Maybe it's time!

Comment: Doesn't work. 

Your link would need an id of "link" for your ajax:complete handler to work.